# Copy object with "=" operator, changes not reflected in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So this is a very simple question. Let's say we have an array of several objects. Then, with the usage of `find` function we select one object from array. If I change properties of that object, the changes are reflected in the array, as expected.

However, if I define a new variable with a different object and set it to the selected item from the array, the changes are not visible. E.g.:

```
let 
arr = [
  {
    id: 1, 
    name: 'James', 
    prop: {
      my: 'prop'
    }
  }, 
  {
    id:2, 
    name:'Delaney', 
    prop: 
    {
      my: 
      'prop'
    }
  }
],
item = arr.find(x => x.id > 1),
newItem = 
    {
      id: 3, 
      name:'test', 
      prop: {
        my: 'test'
      }
    };

item = newItem;
console.log(newItem);
console.log(item);
console.log(arr);
```

Here I'd expect that since both `item` and `newItem` have the SAME value, the changes will be seen in `arr` as well, but it is not the case. If I change a single property on `item`, then the changes are visible. What gives?

A working example: http://jsbin.com/roxecofesa/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: `newItem` does not exist in your array, so you shouldn't expect anything to change.

Comment: yes, but I override the `item` with the content of the `newItem` and `item` does have a reference to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine a variable `item` as a signpost. It points to where in memory is the object returned by the function `arr.find()`. Next you create another signpost `newItem` that points towards your newly created object.

When you write `item = newItem` you are saying: "Hey roadsign `item`, can you point towards the object that is currently pointed by `newItem`?"

Comment: ahhh I see, so `item` loses the reference to array, but is redirected to the reference of  `newItem`, which has nothing to do with the existing array?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this!